# Ng-File-Upload with MVC & Web API - keep getting "404 Not Found"

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I need to allow image upload in my AngularJS + WebAPI project. to achieve this I am using ng-file-upload according to this sample code: http://monox.mono-software.com/blog/post/Mono/233/Async-upload-using-angular-file-upload-directive-and-net-WebAPI-service/

with a few adjustments to the post code to look like this:

```
$scope.onFileSelect = function ($files) {
    console.log("on file select is running!");
    //$files: an array of files selected, each file has name, size, and type.
    for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
        var $file = $files[i];
        (function (index) {
            Upload.upload({
                url: "/api/Uploads/Upload", // webapi url
                method: "POST",                   
                file: $file
            }).progress(function (evt) {
                // get upload percentage
                console.log('percent: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                // file is uploaded successfully
                console.log(data);
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                // file failed to upload
                console.log(data);
            });
        })(i);
    }
}
```

I have quite a few web API controllers already and I added a new one according to the code sample in the link above (that inherits from **System.web.http.ApiController** instead of the "regular" **Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controller** class):

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UploadsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost] // This is from System.Web.Http, and not from System.Web.Mvc        
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Upload()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        var provider = GetMultipartProvider();
        var result = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

        // On upload, files are given a generic name like "BodyPart_26d6abe1-3ae1-416a-9429-b35f15e6e5d5"
        // so this is how you can get the original file name
        var originalFileName = GetDeserializedFileName(result.FileData.First());

        // uploadedFileInfo object will give you some additional stuff like file length,
        // creation time, directory name, a few filesystem methods etc..
        var uploadedFileInfo = new FileInfo(result.FileData.First().LocalFileName);



        // Through the request response you can return an object to the Angular controller
        // You will be able to access this in the .success callback through its data attribute
        // If you want to send something to the .error callback, use the HttpStatusCode.BadRequest instead
        var returnData = "ReturnTest";
        return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { returnData });
    }
```

The problem is, i keep getting "404 not found" when posting.

I tried:

1. all stack overflow answers
2. online answers
3. removing the content of the "Upload" function, and changing to MVC's Controller base class -> still same result.
4. changing the name of "Upload" method to "Post" and posting to "/api/uploads" -> same 404.

Please help!
thanks!

**EDIT**

this is the browser "Network" tab:
[image: All previous posts succeeded, just the upload fails]

- I am using HTTPS
- this was tested "live" (without localhost) = same result.

**EDIT2**

my routes:

```
  app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

these are the only routes that are declared.

**EDIT3**

I am 100% sure the problem is me using "**ApiController**" as base class instead of "**Controller**". i added a new controller and i can access it no problem. now just making it work as i don't have " Request.Content " in "**Controller**" - any ideas?

I see 2 possibilities to make it work:

1. pass HttpRequestMessage as a parameter to the method:

   public async Task Post([FromBody]HttpRequestMessage request)

but i am getting HTTP 500 as i don't know how to pass from angular's POST.

or:

2. get **Request.Content** to resolve under Controller (no idea how).

has someone managed to do this? thanks!

Comment: anyone? i am really stuck here....

Comment: You tried *all* Stack Overflow answers already? Wow. – If there’s a 404, then the server rejects the request. Try to post to that URL with a normal XMLHttpRequest to see if the server is responding properly. Once you get that working, replace it by an actual file upload.

Comment: @poke i mean related answers. the post target is the same as all my other post "/api/[contoller]" - why should it reject this one? and also how can i send a normal XMLHttpRequest request? thanks!

Comment: If every other endpoint works fine, then that’s even more odd, so you should definitely check to see if the request is working properly. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) for information on how to use XHR. Also, you should try debugging in C# to see if the request arrives and what causes the failure. And be sure to check your browser’s network development tools as well, to see if the URL is really correct.

Comment: @poke when trying to debug, even in the constructor of the web API controller, it doesn't reach it, thus maybe a routing problem? or am i wrong to expect the constructor to run at this point?

Comment: Why are you using https with localhost?

Comment: @AmiramKorach - thanks for taking time for this - this server doubles as a testing env so it has HTTPS on it. you think this is the problem?

Comment: by the way it behaves the same way with the "live" version (AKA non localhost) = 404 not found.

Comment: Did you try it without https?

Comment: are you able to open it in the browser at all ?? Seems to be a routing issue at first sight.

Comment: @tarkil I see RouteAttribute in your controller and your url seems to be normal like the default web api route. please use only one at a time. By the way, you should use RoutePrefixAttribute for controller and RouteAttribute for method if you are only using attribute routing. Also, if you are using attribute routing, make sure you have called config.MapAttributeRoutes() in your WebApiConfig.cs file

Comment: @Alok browsing to both ".../api/Uploads/" and ".../api/Uploads/Upload" gives out 404 in the network tab of chrome's dev tool

Comment: @BhushanFirake what do you nean use one? remove either the "[Route()]" tag in the web api controller or what? thanks!

Comment: i checked and when i browse directly to the controller, i get the GET from other controllers, but from this one i get 404.

Comment: @tarkil I mean to say, use either default routing or attribute routing. Just one at a time.

Comment: @tarkil I have never used square brackets in Route attribute, can you try changing your route attribute to `[RoutePrefix("api/uploads")]` and annotating your method with `[Route("upload")]`. By the way, it is not restful, you can just keep it `[Route("")]` and request `POST /api/uploads`

Comment: @tarkil also, please add your WebApi routing section in the question to make a better understanding of what routes you have registered. Definitely seems a routing issue to me.

Comment: @BhushanFirake added my routes at the end of the question "EDIT2" - thanks!

Comment: @BhushanFirake changing the routing attributes didn't help.

Comment: I am 100% sure the problem is me using "ApiController" as base class instead of "Controller". i added a new controller and i can access it no problem. now just making it work as i don't have " Request.Content " in "Controller" - any ideas?

Comment: Please post your Web API routes. In your question, you only have posted the MVC routes. Also, post your startup configuration (namely the calls to register your MVC and WebAPI routes, including the order you are calling them). Most likely, you have MVC registered first, which is causing your routes to be registered in the wrong order.

Comment: there are no more routes defined.

Comment: Then your WebApi configuration is incomplete. WebApi is an independent framework from MVC and requires its own startup code. It sounds as if you haven't even enabled WebApi in startup, which is why it doesn't work.

Comment: Which version of MVC/WebApi are you using?

Comment: using vNEXT (so latest versions of both)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem i posted in EDIT3 by using:

```
 if (Request.Form.Files != null && Request.Form.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
            var contentType = file.ContentType;

            using (var fileStream = file.OpenReadStream())
            {
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await fileStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                    FileStream newFS = new FileStream(Settings.UserImagesDir + "\\name.png", FileMode.Create);
                    memoryStream.WriteTo(newFS);
                    newFS.Close();                     
                }
            }
        }
```

and all this in a regular web api controller that inherits from **Controller**.

thanks everyone for your help, although no one solved it you all pushed me in the right direction.

Comment: I dont understand that how changing in your action solved your 404 issue.

Comment: @MohammedDawoodAnsari the change in the base class solved the 404, the change in the action itself came to compensate for the loss of "Request.Content" that derived from the former base class. i described it in EDIT3.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your routing is misconfigured for the URL `/api/Uploads/Upload`. In order to make it match, you have to specify a template for the method `Upload`, since it is not actually named after an HTTP method.

```
[HttpPost("upload")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Upload()
{
    // code omitted...
}
```